# HTML back-ground color and font not showing in Chrome or Firefox

Tags: html, css

I just finished debugging my HTML file but the web page is not loading the colors and I'm not sure what's wrong. I've uploaded it to w3c css validator and it says there are no errors, yet it still won't show the background colors. I'm wondering if  element is not loading it properly? Can someone take a look and let me know if there are any errors? I've added comments where there were errors.

This is what the page should look like:

[image]

This is what my page looks like in Chrome and Firefox:

[image]

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* removed .txt from the .css file name */
/*
   New Perspectives on HTML5 and CSS3, 8th Edition
   Tutorial 2
   Coding Challenge 4

   Author: 
   Date: 

   Filename: code2-4.css

*/

div {
   background-color: rgb(255, 171, 171); /* Missing commas */
   padding: 10px; /*removed size from padding*/
   font-size: 1.2em;
}

aside {
   background-color: rgb(209,227,107);
   padding: 0 20px;
}

aside h1 {
   font-size: 1.9em;
   font-family: Segoe, Verdana, sans-serif; /* The syntax was incorrect. It should be "font-family" */
   line-height: 0.8em;
   margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

aside h2 {
   margin-top: 5px;
   font-family: Segoe, Verdana, sans-serif; /* The syntax was incorrect. It should be "font-family"*/
   font-size: 1.2em; /* missing the 'm' after 'e'. */
}

aside p {
   font-size: 1.1em;
   text-indent: 1em; /* "indent" spelled wrong. Added the 'n' after i. */
}

aside p:first-of-type { /* missing the "-" between first-of-type. */
   text-indent: 0em;
}

@charset "utf-8";

/*
   New Perspectives on HTML5 and CSS3, 8th Edition
   Tutorial 2
   Coding Challenge 2
   
   Filename: code2-2_layout.css

*/

body {
   width: 900px;
}

img {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0px;
}

div {
   float: left;
   width: 300px;
   height: 580px;
}

aside {
   float: left;
   width:540px;
   height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <!--
   New Perspectives on HTML5 and CSS3, 8th Edition
   Tutorial 2
   Coding Challenge 4

   Author: 
   Date: 
   Filename: code2-4.html
   -->
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Coding Challenge 2-4</title>
   <link href="code2-4_layout.css" rel="stylesheet" /> <!-- missing the link to the style sheet. -->
   <link href="code2-4.css" rel="stylesheet" /> <!-- missing the link to the style sheet. -->
</head>
<body>
   <header><img src="code2-4_img.png" alt="The Sci-Fi Control Room" /></header>

   <div>
      <p>Welcome to the Sci-Fi Control Room</p>
      <p>I started this blog in order to share my latest fiction with my
         readers and to post reviews and comments on the world of Science Fiction
         and Fantasy. From time to time, we'll have interviews with other
         great authors in the Sci-Fi and Fantasy markets as well as give you
         the inside scoop on upcoming conventions.</p>
      <p>But this is also your forum to share your ideas and enthusiasm.
         You can send me your comments and ideas; but please do NOT send me your
         fiction. I'm not a publisher and I will NOT read them. This is the
         Sci-Fi Control Room and I'm the one in control.</p>

   </div>

   <aside>
      <h1>The Star Tunnel</h1>
      <h2>by Kei Yang</h2>
      <p>In her latest science-fiction novel, Yang explores the idea of
         quantum tunneling and a machine built to instantly transport the rider
         to the end of the universe. Teleportation is an old sci-fi concept and
         one that I thought had been wrung dry. Yang has proven me wrong.
         Reminiscent of the best of Niven's teleportation series stories from
         the 70's, Yang is concerned, not so much with the technology of teleportation,
         as much as its effect on society, morals, and religion.</p>
      <p>To be sure, this is not just philosophical track masquerading as a
         SF novel (though Yang's always-fascinating philosophical ruminations are
         here in abundance). Fans of hard-hitting action-packed SF will have plenty
         to entertain them and Yang pulls several rabbits out of her hat to
         surprise any reader. I thought I knew all of the tricks of the trade
         and Yang's denouement surprised even me.</p>
      <p>My only complaint is that the novel begins slowly with a bit too much
         emphasis on the technobabble associated with teleportation. Why do some
         authors insist on turning whole chapters into a physics thesis? However
         don't skip the second chapter or else you'll miss a hilarious misadventure
         involving two teleportation devices and a rather annoying cat. </p>
   </aside>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: ][2]]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuAkD.png)

I just used the Javescript/HTML/CSS snippet tool and when I ran my code it looked like the first picture. I've tried running the code in Edge, IE, Firefox and Chrome. Edge and IE won't load it but Firefox and Chrome don't show the background colors and the text isn't correct. I'm also wondering if Segoe is spelled wrong? My IDE said it was spelled Segue but when I updated the spelling nothing changed.

Comment: A possible explanation is that you failed to load the css file. Did you make sure that that is not the case? (what does the comment `<!-- missing the link to the style sheet. -->` mean?)

Comment: I have to place comments when I'm debugging code for my class. But I will take a look at the file again and make sure that I have the correct file in there.